# Port 80 forwarding on a broadband connection

Tags: networking, server, iptables, port-forwarding

We have an Ubuntu 20.04 server that connected to a broadband on enp1s0. We also have a security camera connected to the server on iface enp2s0. The camera has a gateway on 192.168.240.1 and serves its web application on 192.168.240.2. The current routes are:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.4.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp1s0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 enp1s0
192.168.240.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp2s0
192.168.240.2   192.168.240.1   255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 enp2s0
```

The idea is that someone from a remote monitoring location can browse to the edge computer's external ip, and control the camera. So what we think we need to do is forward requests on port 80 from the modem to the camera. We are restricted to using iptables, so no use of ufw, which is disabled.

We have created the following script to setup the forwarding:

```
IP=192.168.4.17
CAM_IP=192.168.240.2
PORT=80
 
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -F -t nat
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $CAM_IP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d $CAM_IP --dport 80 -j SNAT --to $IP
```

So far we have been able to get this to work on a computer in the same subnet, but have had no success with a request from outside (we did set up port forwarding in the modem). The forums have many variations on this scenario, but we weren't able to find this exact one.

Any help resolving this would be appreciated!

Comment: It is very unlikely that you are able to forward port 80 over a cellular connection. In fact, it is unlikely that you can forward any port over a cellular connection. Have you considered setting up a VPN or bastion of some kind?

Comment: Does the internet connection function properly otherwise? Do any other protocols like ssh work, remote to the server itself? The IP architecture is a bit confusing.. In these situations a diagram would be beneficial. Is the two ***.155 IPs a typo?

Comment: @Beefy_Swain Agreed, it was unrealistic to think that would be possible. We have set up a reverse ssh connection which allows us to ssh into the proxy server and from there to the edge computer. After some tinkering that works. I will update the question to focus on the broadband connection.